# VSPackage development using C++, how do i initialize my package when start visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vspackage

My package is developed with C++, VS2015.
For example, I defined some command in project menu and tool bar, when I startup VS, the tool bar menu is fine, but the command in project menu doesn't appear, then I have to tap whatever button in toolbar menu and then the command in project menu come back.
I want my package initialize project menu command when start up visual studio or open a peoject.

My code like this

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CYHMExtensionsPackage : 
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CYHMExtensionsPackage, &CLSID_YHMExtensions>,
    // Provides the implementation for IVsPackage to make this COM object into a VS Package.
    public IVsPackageImpl<CYHMExtensionsPackage, &CLSID_YHMExtensions>,
    public IOleCommandTargetImpl<CYHMExtensionsPackage>,
    // Provides consumers of this object with the ability to determine which interfaces support extended error information.
    public ATL::ISupportErrorInfoImpl<&__uuidof(IVsPackage)>
{
public:
// Provides a portion of the implementation of IUnknown, in particular the list of interfaces
// the CYHMExtensionsPackage object will support via QueryInterface
BEGIN_COM_MAP(CYHMExtensionsPackage)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IVsPackage)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IOleCommandTarget)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(ISupportErrorInfo)
END_COM_MAP()
VSL_DECLARE_NOT_COPYABLE(CYHMExtensionsPackage)
public:
    CYHMExtensionsPackage():m_dwEditorCookie(0), m_MyToolWindow(GetVsSiteCache())
    {
        GetYHMVSSolution();
    }
    ~CYHMExtensionsPackage()
    {
    }
...
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Maybe you shouldn't place code initializing other methods in the constructor for your class.

Implement the following method in your class .h file and set a breakpoint at Sleep

```
void PostSited(IVsPackageEnums::SetSiteResult /*result*/)
{
    Sleep(2500);//initilialize will sleep for some time
}
```

2. Be sure to have the proper autoload registry key setup in your projects **.pkgdef** file, in my case it is after the vspackage's project has been created from the wizard {f1536ef8-92ec-443c-9ed7-fdadf150da82} and then put in your project's guid where it says 03be14ec-1a85-4c5c-a1f4-723d189c2e4c

Here is an example autoload:

```
[$RootKey$\AutoLoadPackages\{f1536ef8-92ec-443c-9ed7-fdadf150da82}]
"{03be14ec-1a85-4c5c-a1f4-723d189c2e4c}"=dword:00000000
```

3. More information on which guid to select can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.uicontextguids80.aspx
4. Now press F5 and you should hit the breakpoint. You can verify if the registry key was correctly set in the registry by navigating to

   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0Exp_Config\AutoLoadPackages\{f1536ef8-92ec-443c-9ed7-fdadf150da82}

   (where {f1536ef8-92ec-443c-9ed7-fdadf150da82} is the guid you selected from step 3) and looking for your project's guid [again, in my case it's 03be14ec-1a85-4c5c-a1f4-723d189c2e4c, but yours must be different]. You would need to add it manually if it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

VS Packages should be designed to load when needed, and not forced to load when the VS IDE (devenv.exe) is launched. If everyone forced their packages to load on VS launch, you'd be waiting a very long time for Visual Studio to actually start.

What you **should** be doing, is making use of the [AutoLoadPackages registry key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166762.aspx), to specify which activation contexts should load your package. This is super easy with a VB or C# based package project, as all you need to do is add a [ProvideAutoLoad attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.provideautoloadattribute.aspx) to your package object.

But for C++ based packages, you will need to manually edit the .pkgdef to add the desired entries.

That all being said, menu commands are defined by your .VSCT file, so chances are the problem here is with your .VSCT file and how you are declaring or parenting the menu command you are attempting to add to the project context menu.

Use the [EnableVSIPLogging registry key trick](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dr._ex/2007/04/17/using-enablevsiplogging-to-identify-menus-and-commands-with-vs-2005-sp1/), to verify you have identified the proper guid:id pair for the context menu you are interested in.

(hint) If you are using VS 2015, you can also set this via [Mads Kristensen's Extensibility Tools extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ab39a092-1343-46e2-b0f1-6a3f91155aa6). I recommend this especially if you're editing .pkgdefs, .vsixmanifests and the like.